# How can I suppress Dokka documentation for specific classes?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka

I'm trying to generate nice API docs for a library I'm working on, and I haven't found a way to keep Dokka from generating empty documentation pages for generated code like the `R` class in my package.

I'm already using

```
packageOptions {
  prefix = "android"
  suppress = true
}
```

to suppress documentation at a package level, but is there a way to prevent generation of documentation for specific classes in the package I *do* want to generate documentation for? Or build a whitelist of classes so Dokka only generates docs for those classes?

Or is there another doc generator for Kotlin that I should look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can specify class names as well as prefixes in the `packageOptions` section. You just specify them the same as you would a prefix.

```
packageOptions {
  prefix = "com.fqdn.MyPackage.R"
  suppress = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the desired classes as `internal`.
Doing so, the documentation will not be generated for internal ones.
Also useful to configure in gradle file dokka like this:

```
    named("main"){
        //sourceRoots.setFrom(file("src/main/java/com/cujo/sb/util"))
        includeNonPublic.set(false)
        skipEmptyPackages.set(true)
        reportUndocumented.set(true)
        skipDeprecated.set(false)
    }
```